# Difficulty getting MVC app to run on AppHarbor

Tags: appharbor

I have AppHarbor hooked up to an app in Bitbucket.  AppHarbor seems to be retrieving the latest from Bitbucket and deploying.
When I go to my app's page, however, I get this error:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to
>   locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server
>   Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime
>   feature is enabled.)]

I have the SQL Server add-on installed, and tried to make sense of this: [ASP.NET MVC 4 - Application not accepting new connection string - AppHarbor Deploy Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567260/asp-net-mvc-4-application-not-accepting-new-connection-string-appharbor-depl)  and this: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/add-ons/using-sequelizer.

Any other tips would be appreciated...

Comment: Did you specify, in your application, to use the SQL connection string name supplied by AppHarbor? Moreover, did you assign an alias to SQL instance to make AppHarbor use the connection string name you were expecting within your application?

Comment: @Brad - I have a Connectionstring alias set up, and a connection string with the same name on web.config.  I'm not sure where to add the connection string provided by AppHarbor, since AppHarbor says: "This is the connection string that will be injected by AppHarbor".
Thanks for the reply; this is my first attempt at deploying an MVC app to AppHarbor, and it's still pretty confusing...

Comment: By chance are the providers the same with both deployments? (e.g. `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` on Appharbor, whereas it may be set as `providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"` locally?)

Comment: @Brad - "providerName="System.Data.SqlClient".  I never change that.