# C# SQL Server Connection Issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlconnection

I am having problems connecting to a SQL Server database from C#.

The exception that returns is the login has failed for the specified user, which is clear enough. However, I am not sure why it fails as the username and password are definitely correct. Are there any settings I need to enable on the SQL Server to allow this to happen, as it is a default express install,

Thanks,

Below is my connection code if I'm missing anything obvious.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=furniture_display;User ID=login;Password=login");
        con.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("all ok");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: connect to sql server using the credentials you are passing in connection string i.e SQL Server UserID and the Password.  via SSMS and execute `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` . what ever this query return us that value in your Data Source property of your connection string.

Comment: If that user is definitely set up with those credentials, this should work. Have you mapped your database login to the `furniture_display` database? And can you post the exact error message which is returned?

Comment: Is that login and password a Windows user or aSQL Server user?

Comment: @Oliver this may be trivial but have you tried removing the spaces for your datasource ?  `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS` or try `Data Source=SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS` .Additionally if you have SSMS I would connect to the instance to verify

Comment: Hi all, I had not correctly mapped (thought I had, sorry!) the server user to the database in the correct way and that stopped the login to the SSMS. Apologies and thank you all very much for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code `Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS`, you'r trying to connect to a local server. If so you don't need any **ID** and **Password**. And be aware of using `Catalog`, it's somehow tricky and I hate it. To know how it's working, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949774/what-is-the-point-of-initial-catalog-in-a-sql-server-connection-string) out.

Actually I'm using this code and it works like a charm:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server = localhost; Database = furniture_display; Integrated Security=True;");
```