# ASP.NET Web service - How to connect it to database using connection string ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I want to retrieve all the registered users from my application using web service in `ASP.NET`. However, I have problem with connection string.

```
public static String getRegisteredUsers(string usernameCode)
    {
        string username = "";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyDatabaseConnectionString1");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Username from Users where usernameCode = '" + usernameCode.ToUpper() + "'", con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            username = dr["username"].ToString();
        }

        dr.Close();
        con.Close();

        return username;
    }
```

This `MyDatabaseConnectionString1` is the connection string that I use for the table that I want to retrieve the information from. It works for that table, but not when it comes to web service.

```
<add name="MyDatabaseConnectionString1" connectionString= "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\Fitness\App_Data\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Should I use the same connection string for web service or it's done somehow differently ?

This is the error:
[image]

Comment: The connection string is missing the initial catalog?  See the [MSDN page.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0(v=vs.110).aspx) However, unless you have multiple databases on that server, [it shouldn't matter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1949790/6530134)... [possibly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949774/what-is-the-point-of-initial-catalog-in-a-sql-server-connection-string#comment1862783_1949790)?

Comment: SqlConnection expects the connection string, not the name of the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure System.Configuration assembly is referenced.
Use this syntax:

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: Ye that works. Wondered that could've been the problem but didn't know how to display it with syntax.

Comment: Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `MyDatabaseConnectionString1` (*name* of the connection string) directly as input for `SqlConnection` (which expects *connection string* as the input). Do this instead:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
... //continue as what you have done
```

You declare your `MyDatabaseConnectionString1` in the `.config` file. The `SqlConnection` does not read your `.config` file but take the `connStr` input. Thus you get the error. You should read your connection string in the `.config` file by using `ConfigurationManager` available in the `System.Configuration` namespace. Then you use the `connStr` resulting from reading the `.config` file