# execute SQL script with USE DATABASE in C#

Tags: c#

My query file looks like this:

```
USE DB_A
GO
SELECT * FROM sch.table;
```

but my connection string, because of some reason, should be forced to set as `@"Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DB_B; ......"`

As `ExecuteNonQuery()` doesn't support `GO`, this query will be separated into two parts, i.e, actual code looks like this:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = ConnString;
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

conn.open();    
cmd.ComandText = "USE DB_A";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.ComandText = "SELECT * FROM sch.table";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.close();
```

it seems`USE DATABASE` doesn't work, it is still reporting errors `cannot find object sch.table` when executing.

is there any neat solution other than changing my query file or my connection string?

Comment: If you connection strings point to particular db then you dont need to use command like `USE DB_A`. just remove that and test it

Comment: What's the db you are using? MS SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: As it is pointed out at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949774/what-is-the-point-of-initial-catalog-in-a-sql-server-connection-string, Initial Catalog can be used to specify the database you want to execute your queries. So once you have specified the correct DB there, you don't have to make use of `USE DB_A`.

Comment: you can try with transaction for your first use database query and commit , then try executing your select . Not tested though, just an idea

Comment: @Christos But he said that thec onnection string should refer to `DB_B`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman MS SQL server

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed `USE` doesn't work here. What you can do is fully reference your objects. So instead of

```
SELECT * FROM sch.table
```

write

```
SELECT * FROM DB_A.sch.table
```

Note that this will only work if you can access DB_A from DB_B with the same credentials you've used to connect to DB_B. If this is not the case you'll have to use a seperate connection to DB_A.

Comment: 'other than changing my query file' is mentioned; the file content is not controllable and changable in my side, the only thing is expected is that file can be executed normally in the SQL server client.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Where in your code do you use a query file?

Answer (score 0):

A Solution available is just remove the initial catalog `Initial Catalog=DB_B` from connection string. Not a perfect solution to this question, but worked in my case.